# Using Array.map omitting the first element of the array in F#

Tags: f#

I have just started playing with F#, so this question will probably be quite basic...

I would like to read a text file line by line, and then ignore the first line and process the other lines using a given function. So I was thinking of using something along the lines of:

```
File.ReadAllLines(path)
|> Array.(ignore first element)
|> Array.map processLine
```

what would be an elegant yet efficient way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no simple function to skip the first line in an array, because the operation is not efficient (it would have to copy the whole array), but you can do that easily if you use lazy sequences instead:

```
File.ReadAllLines(path) 
|> Seq.skip 1
|> Seq.map processLine
```

If you need the result in an array (as opposed to `seq<'T>`, which is an F# alias for `IEnumerable<'T>`), then you can add `Seq.toArray` to the end. However, if you just want to iterate over the lines later on, then you can probably just use sequences.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to Tomas' answer, which I generally agree with.  One thing to watch is what happens if your array or sequence contains no lines.  (Or fewer lines than you want to skip.)  In that case, Seq.skip will throw an exception.  The most concise way around this that I can think of is:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines fileName
|> Seq.mapi (fun i elem -> i, elem)
|> Seq.choose (fun (i, elem) -> if i > 0 then Some(elem) else None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You skip the first element in an F# array simply by `myArray.[1..]`.  Gotta love how elegant this language is.